# how to check user is active on page in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How we can check the mouse and key events in angular 2 globally, I meant at root level. I want to call one service when user is interacting not idle with the application. Please help me and suggest some good solution on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your top level component, create an observable from an event of a Document object and invoke your service, for example:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
...

const clicks$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
clicks$.subscribe(x => console.log('Calling my service here'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just one more confirmation, Will it be expensive in terms of the subscription will be open at the root level?

Comment: Well, this is what you asked for, right? In my code sample, your service will be invoked on any click event.  To make it less expensive, provide some business logic in your service to use some state variable that at certain conditions would reduce the number of invocations of lengthy operations.